# JavaScript Email Validation with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

I am currently writing a binding handler in knockout to use the regular expression to validate the email. This is done using the RFC 2822 compliant regex.

I am trying to use RegExp('MY_REG_EXP')

```
MY_REG_EXP = [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

But since I am using single quotes (code quality purpose) at the beginning it is causing the binding handler not to validate the contents on update.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.emailInput = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
            ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext);
        },

        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).on('keydown', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                regex = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9!#$%&/\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\/.[a-z0-9!#$%&/\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\/.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$');
            if (value.trim() !== '' && !regex.test(value)) {
                element.style.backgroundColor = '#EDB2B2';
            } else {
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }
        }
    };
```

Any feedback on my approach is appreciated.

Comment: "_I am using single quotes (code quality purpose)_" Can you explain why you consider single quotes to be of better code quality?

Comment: It's fine if you chose to use single quotes, but if that means you have to escape single quotes in a string, use double quotes for that string, instead. Don't blindly follow style guidelines. Only apply them where ___possible___.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript regex email validation has been obsolete for half a decade at least.

```
<input type="email" />
```

Done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm with older browsers too.

Comment: This too works. But not sure how it behaves with the knockout hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by using the /\ escape characters. Single quotes check is part of our build process and I didnt want to make an exception unnecessarily.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.emailInput = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
            ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext);
        },

        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                regex = new RegExp('[a-z0-9!#$%&/\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&/\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?');
            if (value.trim() !== '' && !regex.test(value)) {
                element.style.backgroundColor = '#EDB2B2';
            } else {
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: This is the solution I wish to have for the current email box